# Ruby -- run a local gem server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm a Ruby novice working on a Rails application. We're trying to speed up our installs by running a local gem server instead of always going out to rubygems.org. I found that running the command:

```
gem server
```

sets this up, with the server running at localhost 8808. However when I add a source line for that URL to my Gemfile, and then run "bundle install", it fails after a minute or so saying:

```
Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: bad response Not Found  404 (http://localhost:8808/gems/rake-10.3.1.gem)
An error occurred while installing rake (10.3.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install rake -v '10.3.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

If I browse to that server, I see a page saying that Rake, version 10.3.1 is installed, but when I go to the listed URL, I do get a 404 page. After running the gem install command, I still get a 404 page, but the bundle install gets a step further and fails with:

```
Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: bad response Not Found  404 (http://localhost:8808/gems/activesupport-3.2.12.gem)
An error occurred while installing activesupport (3.2.12), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install activesupport -v '3.2.12'` succeeds before bundling.
```

What's going on here? I have both source lines in my Gemfile, so I'd expect the bundler to go out to rubygems.org for anything it couldn't find locally, but it also seems like the gems are in fact installed locally already. Do I have to run individual installs on each gem dependency? I'm sure I'm doing something obviously wrong here, but I'm don't know what it is.

Answer (score 1):

This is a decent walkthrough of a few situations you might encounter while setting up a gem server: http://guides.rubygems.org/run-your-own-gem-server/

This one isn't half-bad either, if you're looking to just use local versions of gems (though this technique doesn't set up a separate gem server): https://coderwall.com/p/tqdrhq

Comment: Yes, that first link is where I found out about the "gem server" command. Is that a decent walk through? I found it a bit sparse. It called out the existence of the tool, but pretty much left it at that. I'm making a certain progress with the server though just by trial and error. The trick seems to be install once with rubygems.org, and then point the server at the gemset you were using. However, bundle install still can't run without sourcing rubygems.org, though it does seem to be getting most gems from the local server.